# jQuery AJAX Call Returns null Response Time to Time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a link on my page which creates an AJAX call the page itself and returns a value. Response generated by server, which created successfully, becames empty or sometimes error function of the AJAX. I tried almost everything and couldn't come up with a solution.

Here is my AJAX function:

```
var Ajax = {
    AjaxCall: function (uri, jsonData, callBack, postParams) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: uri + ((uri.indexOf("?") > -1) ? "&" : "?") + "rand=" + new Date().format("ssmmHHddMMyyyy"),
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                Ajax.AjaxCall_CallBack(msg, callBack, postParams);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                Ajax.AjaxCall_CallBack_Error(msg);
            }
        });
    },

    AjaxCall_CallBack: function (msg, callBack, postParams) {
        callBack(msg, postParams);
    },

    AjaxCall_CallBack_Error: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.responseText);
    }
}
```

and the function makes the AJAX call

```
Ajax.AjaxCall('dummypage.aspx?ajax=6&edit=1&uID=' + uID, null, callback_func, [uID, 'Test Text', 0])
```

The value generated from server is something like this:

```
Table tbl;
TableRow tr;
TableCell tc;
Label lbl;
DropDownList ddl;

tbl = new Table();
tr = new TableRow();

tc = new TableCell();
lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "Choose one"
tc.Controls.Add(lbl);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);

tc = new TableCell();
ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Items.Add("Choose", "-1"));
ddl.Items.Add("First", "1");
ddl.Items.Add("Second", "2");
ddl.ID = "ddlContentType";

tc.Controls.Add(ddl);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);

tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

tbl.RenderControl(hw);
string renderedValue = sb.ToString();
hw.Close();

return HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(renderedValue, true);
```

I don't understand why exact same structure on the same page which has the same procedure works but not this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When there is an error what message is in error: function (msg) ?

Comment: It's also null. What i don't understand is, out of 3 tries, first one empty, second one error, third success.

Comment: BTW, i concluded that this problem occurs in ie9.

Comment: @AndrewWalters Sorry for misleading, the error code is 12031.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gaurav mentioned at [jQuery AJAX Call Returns null Response Time to Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816164/jquery-ajax-call-returns-null-response-time-to-time/14829052#comment20777020_14829052) null data can't be handled correctly on some browsers. I handled the null data as following:

```
function RunAjaxCall(uri, jsonData, callBack, postParams) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: uri + ((uri.indexOf("?") > -1) ? "&" : "?") + "rand=" + new Date().getTime(),
            **data: jsonData != null ? JSON.stringify(jsonData) : {},**
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (msg) {
                Success(msg, callBack, postParams);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                Error(msg);
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have strange ajax/WCF/webservice behavior like this the only thing that can help you is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

It helps to see what is going on and analize request and response.

Anyway as best practice you should pass only data to fill html with ajax and not the entire html

Comment: One of the weird things is: I can't reproduce this situation when fiddler is active! :)

Comment: @atakanozgun murphy's law :D

Comment: @atakanozgun so to troubleshoot, can you check what happens when you hard code data:{} in your method?

Comment: so you know where the culprit is :) one more thing, in firefox you need to put data:{} when no data is being passed or else you will start seeing issues there too.

Comment: Thanks @gaurav your suggestion resolved my issue. I posted an answer refers to your comment.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Take care :)